# SPO start page doesn't get the same menu as our home site

Tags: sharepoint-online, homepage

Yesterday I ran `Set-SPOHomeSite -HomeSiteUrl /path/to/site` to set our home site.
Today, `Get-SPOHomeSite` indicates that the site mentioned is indeed a home site. I also see that the search bar on top of the home site says "Search in SharePoint", which shows that at least one part of migrating our site to become a home site has worked, but don't see any "My Sharepoint" type of link from the home site to our start page, and our start page never got the same menu header and theme as our home page.

Does anyone know what may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my knowledge, Integration between the home site and SharePoint start page (where the branding, theming, header, navigation, and footer elements from the home site are applied to the start page and users can easily navigate between the pages) is not available at this time. Please watch for updates in the Microsoft 365 roadmap.

Reference:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/home-site